# How to statically link a netcdf program in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, build, static, g++, netcdf

I am trying to statically link a very simple program using the netcdf library and g++. The program looks like:

```
#include "netcdf.h"
int main(void)
{
  int ncid, ok;
  ok=nc_create("testing.nc", NC_NOCLOBBER, &ncid);
  ok=nc_close(ncid);
  return(0);
}
```

And works perfectly if I compile it like this:

```
> g++ test.cpp -lnetcdf
```

However, if I try to static compile it, then everything breaks:

```
> g++ -static test.cpp -lnetcdf
/usr/lib64/libnetcdf.a(nc4file.o): In function `sync_netcdf4_file':
(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `H5Fflush'
/usr/lib64/libnetcdf.a(nc4file.o): In function `close_netcdf4_file':
(.text+0x11b): undefined reference to `H5Fclose'
/usr/lib64/libnetcdf.a(nc4file.o): In function `get_netcdf_type':
(.text+0x18b): undefined reference to `H5Tget_class'
/usr/lib64/libnetcdf.a(nc4file.o): In function `get_netcdf_type':
(.text+0x1e9): undefined reference to `H5Tis_variable_str'
(...)
```

Many complains, but the first ones are for hdf5. Searching for an answer, I found this page [at unidata](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf-install.html) that explains one should link with hdf5 and other libs. So I tried:

```
> g++ -static test.cpp -lnetcdf -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lz -lm 
/usr/lib64/libnetcdf.a(liboc_la-ocinternal.o): In function `ocinitialize':
(.text+0x17e): undefined reference to `curl_version_info'
/usr/lib64/libnetcdf.a(liboc_la-http.o): In function `ocsetcurlproperties':
(.text+0xc8): undefined reference to `curl_easy_strerror'
(...)
/usr/lib64/libhdf5.a(H5.o): In function `H5_term_library':
(.text+0x383): undefined reference to `pthread_once'
/usr/lib64/libhdf5.a(H5.o): In function `H5dont_atexit':
(.text+0x11ac): undefined reference to `pthread_once'
(...)
```

Fewer complains and the first ones are from libcurl?? And then hdf5 bragging about pthread. So I used package_config to try to figure out all the dependencies:

```
> pkg-config netcdf --libs --static
-lnetcdf
> pkg-config libcurl --libs --static
-lcurl -lidn -llber -lldap -lrt -lgssapi_krb5 -lssl -lcrypto -lz
```

And finally tried:

```
> g++ -pthread -static testing.cpp -lnetcdf -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lz  -lm \
-lcurl -lidn -llber -lldap -lrt -lgssapi_krb5 -lssl -lcrypto -lz
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgssapi_krb5
/usr/lib64/libldap.a(os-ip.o): In function `ldap_pvt_is_socket_ready':
(...)
```

Which still complains about not finding gssapi_krb5... Now I am stuck because after installing libgssapi-krb5-2 the only thing I got were the shared libraries!!

Does any one know how to static link netcdf programs?

It's gotta be more simple than this!! It is a program with 3 lines of code and I do have the static netcdf libraries... If they are already static, how come I need something else?

By the way, I am using Ubuntu Natty 11.04 in a 64bit Intel machine and the netcdf and hdf5 are installed from the Ubuntu repository:

```
> dpkg --get-selections | grep netcdf
libnetcdf-dev                   install
libnetcdf6                  install
netcdf-bin                  install
netcdf-dbg                  install

> dpkg --get-selections | grep hdf
hdf4-tools                  install
hdf5-tools                  install
hdfview                     install
libhdf4-0                   install
libhdf5-serial-1.8.4                install
libhdf5-serial-dev              install
libjhdf4-java                   install
libjhdf4-jni                    install
libjhdf5-java                   install
libjhdf5-jni                    install
```

Comment: This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netcdf/+bug/1698368) in Ubuntu